# How to kernelize a simple perceptron?

Tags: r, neural-networks, svm, kernel-trick, perceptron

Classification problems with nonlinear boundaries cannot be solved by a simple [perceptron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceptron). The following R code is for illustrative purposes and is based on this [example](http://iamtrask.github.io/2015/07/12/basic-python-network/) in Python):

```
nonlin <- function(x, deriv = F) {
  if (deriv) x*(1-x)
  else 1/(1+exp(-x))
}

X <- matrix(c(-3,1,
              -2,1,
              -1,1,
               0,1,
               1,1,
               2,1,
               3,1), ncol=2, byrow=T)

y <- c(0,0,1,1,1,0,0)

syn0 <- runif(2,-1,1)

for (iter in 1:100000) {
  l1 <- nonlin(X %*% syn0)
  l1_error <- y - l1
  l1_delta <- l1_error * nonlin(l1,T)
  syn0 <- syn0 + t(X) %*% l1_delta
}

print("Output After Training:")
## [1] "Output After Training:"
round(l1,3)
##       [,1]
## [1,] 0.488
## [2,] 0.468
## [3,] 0.449
## [4,] 0.429
## [5,] 0.410
## [6,] 0.391
## [7,] 0.373
```

Now the idea of a [kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_method) and the so-called kernel trick is to project the input space into a higher dimensional space, like so ([sources of pics](http://peekaboo-vision.blogspot.de/2012/12/kernel-approximations-for-efficient.html)):

[image]
[image]

**My question**
How do I make use of the kernel trick (e.g. with a simple quadratic kernel) so that I get a [kernel perceptron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_perceptron), which is able to solve the given classification problem? Please note: This is mainly a conceptual question but if you could also give the necessary code modification this would be great

**What I tried so far**
I tried the following which works alright but I think that this is not the real deal because it becomes computationally too expensive for more complex problems (the "trick" behind the "kernel trick" is not just the idea of a kernel itself but that you don't have to calculate the projection for all instances):

```
X <- matrix(c(-3,9,1,
              -2,4,1,
              -1,1,1,
               0,0,1,
               1,1,1,
               2,4,1,
               3,9,1), ncol=3, byrow=T)

y <- c(0,0,1,1,1,0,0)

syn0 <- runif(3,-1,1)
```

**Full Disclosure**
I posted this question a week ago on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33062899/how-to-kernelize-a-simple-perceptron) but it didn't get much attention. I suspect that here is a better place because it is more a conceptual question than a programming question.

Answer (score 3):

We can construct a "kernel perceptron" by taking the standard perceptron and replacing the inner product $X^\intercal X=\left<X,X\right>$ with the equivalent (due to the "kernel-trick") form K(X,X). This works since we have that the inner product is a map $<\cdot,\cdot>:\mathbb{R}^p\times\mathbb{R}^p\to\mathbb{R}$, which has identical properties to the kernel function $k:\mathbb{R}^p\times\mathbb{R}^p\to\mathbb{R}$. As in the case of the common [Gaussian radial basis function kernel (RBF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_basis_function_kernel):

$$
K(x_i,x_j)=\exp\left(-\frac{{\left|\left|x_i-x_j\right|\right|}^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)
$$

As mentioned in the [Wikipedia page on the kernel perceptron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_perceptron), we select a subset of size $M$ of the inputs and use a linear combination of them to produce our output,

$$
f(x) = \sum\limits_i^M \alpha_i y_i K(x,x_i)
$$

If you've seen the support vector machine ([SVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine)), you'll notice the identical dual. To select the subset of size $M$ to use, we optimize over $\alpha_i$, which represent whether sample $i$ is a support/basis vector of our solution. In the optimization of the $\alpha_i$ we include the weights $\omega_i$ of the original perceptron optimization.

As to your question about not having to compute the projection, you're correct, your input data matrix $X$ is still 2-dimensional. In the computation of the output we replaced a dot product with the kernel function, and *this* is where the 'implicit' calculation in the feature space occurs.

Comment: [Gaussian radial basis function kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_basis_function_kernel), [Support vector machine (SVM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine)

Comment: Thank you - Could you perhaps make your answer more concrete in the sense that you state which lines in the code from above have to be modified in which way. If you don't know R the modifications can of course be stated in pseudocode. I would then happily accept your answer :-)

Comment: The post your linked to that you based your code on is, in my opinion, a poor presentation of perceptrons and back-propagation, though it's surely terse. Do you know how back propagation works and the general perceptron theory?

Comment: Well, up to a point, I would hope. What are you getting at exactly? How would you modify the code above to use the kernel trick with a quadratic kernel?

Comment: Isn't there an $\vec{x}^\intercal \vec{x)$ in the Lagrangian dual of the perception criterion? That's specifically where you replace the inner product with the kernel function evaluation.

Comment: I am afraid I don't know what you are talking about. So what seems to be the problem with pinpointing to the part of the code that has to be modified? (I think the above code should be clear enough) - Thank you again.